# How to retrieve filled PDF from Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I had all filed PDF on Google Chrome, that I accessed from a site. The site lets you fill like

https://www.courts.ca.gov/documents/fl150.pdf

Unfortunately, I hit back from MacBook pro touch pad.
Is there a way to retrieve the filled one from the Chrome cache? I know the time window.

Comment: Could you expand more on the time window?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [similar Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1089807/how-to-recover-lost-fields-entered-on-a-pdf-file-or-prevent-such-data-loss), [Google Chrome Help thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3121696/filled-out-pdf-form-in-chrome-downloaded-to-save-but-all-info-was-gone?hl=en), and [Adobe Support Community post](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/data-in-pdf-form-lost-when-saved-from-google-browser/td-p/8979109), the PDF Viewer does not automatically save the data.

Other browsers provide a warning such as `This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave — information you’ve entered may not be saved`.